# Synonym search in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to retrieve the data from the index using the notion of synonym. When I perform a search with title A I also want to retrieve the documents whose title contains B. For that I set up the following mapping :

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym_filter" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms" : [
                            "A=>A,B"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                        "filter" : ["synonym_filter"] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
            "properties": {
              "title": { 
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer" : "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            }
    }
}
```

I then added 3 documents to my index

```
{
  "title": "C"
}
{
  "title": "B"
}
{
  "title": "A"
}
```

I then used the analysis api to see if it works (everything is ok):

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_custom_index_title/_analyze?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer", 
  "text":     "A"
}
'
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "A",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "B",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}

url -X GET "localhost:9200/my_custom_index_title/_analyze?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer", 
  "text":     "B"
}
'
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "B",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

When I search for title A results are correct :

```
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "A"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.6951314,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_custom_index_title",
                "_id": "i5bb_4IBqFAXxSLAgrDj",
                "_score": 0.6951314,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "A"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_custom_index_title",
                "_id": "jJbb_4IBqFAXxSLAlLBj",
                "_score": 0.52354836,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "B"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I search for B the results are not correct, I just want result who contains B when I search and not A

```
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "B"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.52354836,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_custom_index_title",
                "_id": "i5bb_4IBqFAXxSLAgrDj",
                "_score": 0.52354836,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "A"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_custom_index_title",
                "_id": "jJbb_4IBqFAXxSLAlLBj",
                "_score": 0.52354836,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "B"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For example when I search for computer I wish to obtain laptop, computer, mac. But when I search for mac I only want to get the results for it (not laptop and computer)

I do not understand why the result for the search with B does not return only one result

Answer (score 0):

I understand, in this case as you applied synonym_analyzer as a field analyzer, you indexed the synonyms.
To solve it, you can use synonyms only at search time, adding the parameter "search_analyzer". Note that I added the lowercase filter in the synonym_analyzer because the standard analyzer applies lowercase by default.

To get token synonyms for Term B do this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "expand":"false",
            "synonyms": [
              "A=>A,B"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym_filter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer but I I think I described my problem wrong, I just updated my question

Comment: Hi, I understand your doubt and edited my answer.